# Write-Traffic Analysis

Tags: sql-server

I want to assess how much data "churn" (insert, update, delete) a DB is undergoing, preferably per unit time.  For example, I'd like to know how many rows were inserted in the last hour.  Even better, I'd like to know the size of data those rows represented.  I'd like the same information for updates and deletes.

I assume an easy way to check this is by inspecting the transaction log periodically.  What is a simple way to do this?  Is there a DMV that is well suited for this?  Is there a tool I should use?

Comment: One extremely simple way would be to query the backup history tables and check the size of the transaction log backups. Assuming you do take log backups, and the periodicity for this is suitable for your analysis. Another option would be to query the transaction log using fn_dblog() function.